# Standard Deviation manipulation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am studying statistics and I feel as though I have a decent grasp on the subject but I am struggling with one concept (which is quite important), Standard Deviation. I understand that Standard Deviation is seeing how close your data points are to the mean of your data. I know that if it is "Normal" it should make a bell curve and I know the 68%, 95% and 99% rule.

My question is, is there a way to lower the standard deviation of your already plotted data set? Ideally when testing some sort of Hypothesis you would want it to fall within the Mean (or within + or - 1 STD). If it falls outside 1 STD then it is Statistically insignificant to which you need to look into "why" in much further detail.

I am not sure if this falls within more of a data science question because you are trying to manipulate data but any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. If you have the data then the standard deviation is determined, just as the average is determined. You can't lower it by manipulating. If you collect more data from the same experiment you will probably have a lower standard deviation when you compute it from the new, larger data set. I strongly recommend you read Andrew Gelman's blog, about the garden of forking paths:  http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/p_hacking.pdf , http://andrewgelman.com/?s=garden+forking

Comment: Well I guess I was asking it wrong. If you had a STD of some data points and you wanted to optimize those points how could you go about doing so. If you want more of the data to fall within 1 STD and less outside of  1 STD? I am sorry if that is still unclear.

Comment: The data are where they are and spread  as they spread. You can't "optimize" to make more of them be near the mean. You can cheat in various ways, throw out some data, pretend something else is important. That's what Gelman talks about.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bolker, I appreciate your help. I am reading the article as we speak!

Comment: I don't understand the question yet, but the statement that "If it falls outside 1 STD then it is Statistically insignificant" seems quite confused.

Comment: I know I’m still learning statistics. I’m going to have to do more individualized research before asking so that I can receive a more accurate answer. Thank you though for your help.